# How to import large mysql database (innodb , myisam tables) to MySQL NDB cluster

Tags: centos, mysql, freeradius, mysql-cluster

Mysqlcluster used:- `GA 7.4`, Centos 7

I have 30GB each physical memory in 2 datanodes  and SSD 200GB each but the database size(cumulative size of multiple db's belonging to `free radius` ) is around 55GB. Is it possible to migrate my mysql database(myisam/innodb mix tables) to ndb cluster ? i appreciate any useful links suggestions.

Below is my config.ini

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=2
ServerPort=2200
Datadir=/data/mysqlcluster/
FileSystemPathDD=/data/mysqlcluster/
BackupDataDir=/data/mysqlcluster/backup/
#FileSystemPathUndoFiles=/data/mysqlcluster/
#FileSystemPathDataFiles=/data/mysqlcluster/
DataMemory=25165M
IndexMemory=1271M
LockPagesInMainMemory=1

MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=100000
MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=16384

StringMemory=25
MaxNoOfTables=4096
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=2048
MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes=512
MaxNoOfAttributes=24576
MaxNoOfTriggers=14336

### Params for REDO LOG 
FragmentLogFileSize=256M
InitFragmentLogFiles=SPARSE
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=40
RedoBuffer=64M

TransactionBufferMemory=8M

TimeBetweenGlobalCheckpoints=1000
TimeBetweenEpochs=100

TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout=0

### Params for LCP 
MinDiskWriteSpeed=10M
MaxDiskWriteSpeed=20M
MaxDiskWriteSpeedOtherNodeRestart=50M
MaxDiskWriteSpeedOwnRestart=200M
TimeBetweenLocalCheckpoints=20

### Heartbeating 
HeartbeatIntervalDbDb=15000
HeartbeatIntervalDbApi=15000

### Params for setting logging 
MemReportFrequency=30
BackupReportFrequency=10
LogLevelStartup=15
LogLevelShutdown=15
LogLevelCheckpoint=8
LogLevelNodeRestart=15

### Params for BACKUP 
BackupMaxWriteSize=1M
BackupDataBufferSize=24M
BackupLogBufferSize=16M
BackupMemory=40M

### Params for ODIRECT 
#Reports indicates that odirect=1 can cause io errors (os err code 5) on some systems. You must test.
#ODirect=1

### Watchdog 
TimeBetweenWatchdogCheckInitial=60000

### TransactionInactiveTimeout  - should be enabled in Production 
TransactionInactiveTimeout=60000
### New 7.1.10 redo logging parameters 
RedoOverCommitCounter=3
RedoOverCommitLimit=20
### REALTIME EXTENSIONS 
#RealTimeScheduler=1
### REALTIME EXTENSIONS FOR 6.3 ONLY
#SchedulerExecutionTimer=80
#SchedulerSpinTimer=40

### DISK DATA 
SharedGlobalMemory=20M
DiskPageBufferMemory=64M
BatchSizePerLocalScan=512
[NDBD]
NodeId=2
Hostname=10.10.10.20

### REALTIME ASPECTS - THREAD BINDING 
### READ http://johanandersson.blogspot.com/2008/02/mysql-cluster-features-what-they-are.html#realtime
#LockExecuteThreadToCPU=X
#LockMaintThreadsToCPU=Y

[NDBD]
NodeId=3
Hostname=10.10.10.21

### REALTIME ASPECTS - THREAD BINDING 
### READ http://johanandersson.blogspot.com/2008/02/mysql-cluster-features-what-they-are.html#realtime
#LockExecuteThreadToCPU=X
#LockMaintThreadsToCPU=Y

[MYSQLD DEFAULT]
DefaultOperationRedoProblemAction=QUEUE
BatchSize=512
#BatchByteSize=2048K
#MaxScanBatchSize=2048K

[MYSQLD]
NodeId=4
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=5
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=6
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=7

[MYSQLD]
NodeId=8
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=9
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=10
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=11

[MYSQLD]
[MYSQLD]
[MYSQLD]
[MYSQLD]
### SLOTS (one for each ndb_mgmd) FOR HELPER APPLICATIONS SUCH AS ndb_show_tables etc
[MYSQLD]
Hostname=10.10.10.10
### SLOT FOR CMON
[MYSQLD]
Hostname=10.10.10.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But is it really what do you want? Question sounds to me like you found some new and cool called NDB cluster and want to use it without any deeper knowledge. NDB is storage engine, do you know you can do all necessary modification to your DB structure?

Comment: update my post . i should have posted config.ini too.